# Using | pipe character from a $variable makes it treat as just another argument in bash; how to escape it?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, quoting, variable

I have a bash script like this

```
export pipedargument="| sort -n"
ls $pipedargument
```

But it gives the error

```
ls: |: No such file or directory
ls: sort: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be treating the contents of `"| sort -n"` as just an argument passed to `ls`.

How can I escape it so that it's treated as a regular piped command?

I'm trying to conditionally set the `$pipedargument`. I guess I could just conditionally execute different versions of the command but still wondering if there's a way to make this work like above?

Answer (score 11):

You are right that you cannot use `|` that way.  The reason is that the shell has already looked for pipelines and separated them into commands before it does the variable substitution.  Hence, `|` is treated as just another character.

One possible work-around is to place the pipe character literally:

```
$ cmd="sort -n"
$ ls | $cmd
```

In the case that you don't want a pipeline, you can use `cat` as a "nop" or placeholder:

```
$ cmd=cat
$ ls | $cmd
```

This method avoids the [subtleties of eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).  See also [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

#### A better approach: arrays

A more sophisticated approach would use `bash` arrays in place of plain strings:

```
$ cmd=(sort -n)
$ ls | "${cmd[@]}"
```

The advantage of arrays becomes important as soon as you need the command `cmd` to contain quoted arguments.

Comment: Could you clarify why arrays are needed in case of quoted arguments? I ran into that, but don't quite understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @anxieux  A short answer is that a quote, when _inside_ a shell string, loses all  its syntactical power to group words and is instead treated like just any other character.  For a longer and excellent discussion of this issue, see: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 5):

You can `eval`uate the command:

```
eval "ls $pipedargument"
```

or even better define function like:

```
sorted() { "$@" | sort -n; }
```

and later on call it with desired arguments:

```
sorted ls /tmp
```

Comment: Another option would be to define an alias: `alias ls='ls | sort -n'`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function for this. Something like:

```
### usage pipedargument cmd args ###

pipedargument()
{
    sort -n <<< "$( "$@" )"
}

$ pipedargument /sbin/ifconfig eth0
      RX bytes:5904986765 (5.4 GiB)  TX bytes:714370767 (681.2 MiB)
      RX packets:5981427 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4403989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      inet addr:XXX.XXX.X.XX  Bcast:XXX.XXX.X.XXX  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: xx00::0x0x:00xx:xx0:000/00 Scope:Link
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0x:0x:00:x0:00:00
```